# Batch file: Automate VSS Snapshot checks

Tags: batch-file, command, volume-shadow-service

I'm looking for a way to create a VSS snapshot for all drives on a server, to ensure that the functionality is working as expected - after which i would need to delete the snapshots - so far I've been keeping it simple.

```
 vssadmin create shadow /for=C: >> C:\temp\vssoutput.txt
 vssadmin create shadow /for=E: >> C:\temp\vssoutput.txt

 vssadmin delete shadows /for=C:
 vssadmin delete shadows /for=E:
```

as time goes by, i've starting coming across servers with F:\, G:\ or even SQL mount points - so I'm looking to automate this script a little more.

Ideally i would like to run a check on drives (wmic Volume get Capacity, Name) , then set them as a variable and run the vssadmin command based on that variable, looping through all until completed.

any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for /F` to parse the output of a command, like a `wmic` command line.

Firstly, we need to assemble a suitable `wmic` command:

```
wmic LOGICALDISK WHERE (DriveType=3 AND Size^>0) GET Name /VALUE
```

Let us use `LOGICALDISK` rather than than `VOLUME`, because the latter returns also items with no drive letter and system-reserved partitions.
The filter `DriveType=3` includes local disk drives only; the filter `Size>0` excludes non-formatted items (the `>` must be escaped like `^>` in the command line, because `>` has a special meaning -- redirection).
The `/VALUE` switch tells `wmic` to return lines like `Name=C:`.

Then, we wrap around the proper `for /F` command (see also `for /?` for help):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%V in ('
    wmic LOGICALDISK WHERE ^(DriveType^=3 AND Size^^^>0^) ^
        GET Name /VALUE
') do for /F "delims=" %%L in ("%%V") do (
    echo.%%L
    rem Here you may add your `vssadmin` command lines:
    vssadmin create shadow /for=%%L >> C:\temp\vssoutput.txt
    ::
    vssadmin delete shadows /for=%%L
)
```

There are actually two nested `for /F` loops: the outer one parses the output of the `wmic` command line and enumerates all found drives; the inner one iterates exactly once per drive and is intended to remove carriage-return characters which might be appended by the `wmic` command.

To use the above built `wmic` command line within `for /F`, several special characters need to be escaped; this explains the additional `^` symbols.

---

To include also mountpoints in the output of the `wmic` command, you could use the following command line:

```
wmic VOLUME WHERE (DriveType=3 AND FileSystem^>"" AND SystemVolume=FALSE) GET Name
```

The filter `DriveType=3` includes local disk drives only; the filter `FileSystem>""` excludes non-formatted items; the filter `SystemVolume=FALSE` excludes system-reserved partitions.

To parse the output with `for /F`, you need to escape special characters by `^` like above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - i can see that this works a charm for logical drives however, my main issue here is mounpoints - unfortunately Logicaldisk does not provide information on these - hence the reference to use wmic volume command.

any ideas on how this can be accommodated?

Comment: See my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32979578/2): I added a `wmic VOLUME` command line, so mountpoints should now also be included; note that drives with single letters like `D:` are now passed over to `vssadmin` with a trailing `\`, so `D:\`, opposed to the `wmic LOGICALDISK` variant where `D:` is passed over...